# How to replace everything after a specific symbol in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I'm using a proxy checker that outputs the working proxies in the format of:

```
***.***.***.***:*** | ***ms
***.***.***.***:*** | ***ms
***.***.***.***:*** | ***ms
***.***.***.***:*** | ***ms
***.***.***.***:*** | ***ms
```

`*` = any number

How do I make it so that everything after every `|` gets replaced with nothing? (All the ***ms)

Comment: You can use regular expression replacement |.*$

Comment: Corrected code and text format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\|.+$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
            # a space
\|          # a pipe, hev to be escaped
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Just saw this, thanks. I sadly can't choose anything as helpful answer or something cause I'm a new user

Comment: @Cybah: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

you can replace using a regex (on the replace panel, set `Regular Expression` as `Search mode`, and check the `matches newline`), using `\| [0-9]{0,3}ms` as regex, and leave the field empty with the characters to be replaced (You can use the `Ctrl+H` shortcut)

Comment: @JeanpierreBasic if this solves your problem, please mark the answer as correct, 
I would be grateful to you